# Azure Bot works in Framework Composer but not in Azure once published

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service

Due to permissions, I had publish the bot by importing existing resources with the following config file:
[image]

I have triple checked that all the guids are correct and are present in the app registration, web app, and azure bot resources.

In the web app portal, I can see the bot is being successfully deployed from the framework composer in the logs.

In the azure bot resource portal, I set the messaging endpoint to mybot-name.azurewebsites.net/api/messages.

When I attempt to test the web chat in the azure bot resource portal , nothing happens. When testing in composer, it works as expected. When I go to the bot’s URL, it states: ‘Cannot GET /’.  I would greatly appreciate any insight as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

@Christine M,

**Step 1: Check the health status of the channel**.
I would check the Health Status of the Channel by going to Azure Portal, selecting the web app bot resource and Channels and Web Chat, if there is any previous failure, clear the failure on the channel and try again.

**Step 2: How to debug Azure deployed solution by step into source code**
For your case, it looks like your web app is not running in the deployed endpoint, if it runs successfully, you should be able to see the default home page, set a breakpoint, and debug while running from the Azure portal.

Also make sure the App Service in the portal: TLS/SSL settings --> HTTPS Only --> On

Unless you step into your app in Azure deployment mode, it is difficult to say what is happening. Please use the following steps.

- Open Visual Studio (mine is VS 2022) with the project.
- Select Debug | Attach to process. It will display the dialog.
- Select "Microsoft Azure App Services" as the Connection type.
- Select 'Find..." next to the connection type to enumerate your Azure subscriptions and app services.
- In the Azure portal, application settings of your app service, turn on remote debugging.
- Set a breakpoint in your app (Startup.cs or Program.cs)
- Open the browser with your app endpoint (https://..) and enter.
- It will take you to your breakpoint and check the issue.

**Step 3: Verify AppId and AppSecret**
Also, make sure that the Microsoft App ID used in Azure Bot Resource should be same as in the AppSettings.json of the Bot Web App [MicrosoftAppId (or ClientId) and MicrosoftAppPassword (or ClientSecret)]

**Step 3.1: Check the configuration of the app in App Registration** (AAD App Registration)

Make sure the Authentication configuration of the App in App Registration of the AAD (potal.azure.com | App Registration), Redirect URIs should be configured as `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`

**Step 4: Check the configuration of the following pieces in Azure Portal**

- Azure Bot
- Azure App Service
- Azure Service Plan

This web app is deployed in a specific App Service in Azure, check the configuration of the App Service in the Azure portal (portal.azure.com)
[image]

Health Status in the Web Chat channel in Azure Portal should say "Healthy".
I have been through this type of issue, root cause may not be the same, step-by-step debugging will help to address the issue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for the response! 

I cleared the failure on the channel and tried again, this was in the log after:
“There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError”


I also ensured that HTTPS Only is set to on. 

I could not get it running and also am unsure what you mean by set a break point. I would so appreciate any other input.

Comment: @Christine M, any update on your issue

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out, I did not receive a notification with your updated answer, thank you so much! I ended up having an admin publish with the proper permissions but this is good knowledge to have, thank you!

Comment: @ChristineM, please 'upvote the answer' if it helped, so that it can help others in the community looking for help on debugging their issues.